# How do I throw a 404 error from within a java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

How do I throw a 404 error from within a java servlet? My web.xml already specifies what page to show when there is a 404, how do I throw a 404 from within a servlet?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The Servlet API gives you a method to send a 404 or any other HTTP status code.  It's the sendError method of HttpServletResponse:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Comment: After generating this error, whether user will be redirected to error page if configured in web.xml ?

Answer (score 7):

In your `doGet` or `doPost` method you have a parameter `HttpServletResponse res`

404 is a status code which can be set by:

```
res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding Request URL with 404 use this below code

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, request.getRequestURI());
}
```