# Programmatically get error-page from web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servletconfig, servlet-container

I often have redirects like

```
r.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
```

Anyway the `web.xml` already defines `error-page`s.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

How can I programmatically get the configured `error.jsp`?

Comment: I'm not aware of a general API way to do this but it is relatively trivial to read the web.xml as a WAR resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API provides methods to do this without explicitly specifying the error page in your code. See the answer to this question for an example: [How do I throw a 404 error from within a java servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258942/how-do-i-throw-a-404-error-from-within-a-java-servlet)

The main benefit of the answer given is that the servlet container will ensure the correct HTTP error code is returned as part of the response.

Comment: I would argue that this does not answer the original question "How can I programmatically get the configured error.jsp?" The larger question in my mind is how can I programmatically access information from the `web.xml`.